# Parsing list of string containing a delimiter to tree structure

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree

So I have a list of strings like so:

> var drinks = new List(){"Drinks", " * ", "Rum", "Captain Morgan", "Kraken", " * ", "Whiskey",
>   "Laphroaig"}

It needs to return the following:

*Drinks
*Drinks * Rum
*Drinks * Rum * Captain Morgan
*Drinks * Rum * Kraken
*Drinks * Whiskey
*Drinks * Whiskey * Laphroaig

So as seen, anytime a * is encountered, the next string would be treated as a child under the root. So here, Rum would fall under Drinks and Captain Morgan and Kraken would fall under Rum. Whiskey would fall under Drinks and Laphroaig would fall under whiskey.

I know it has to be some sort of tree structure and the only thing I have right now is this:

```
private static Drink GroupDrinks(List<string> drinkNames)
{
        var drink = new Drink() { Children = new List<Drink>() };
        foreach (var drinkName in drinkNames)
        {
            if (drinkName != "*")
            {
                drink.Name = drinkName;
                drinkNames.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            else
            {
                drinkNames.RemoveAt(0);
                drink.Children.Add(GroupDrinks(drinkNames));
            }
        }
        return drink;
    }
```

I figured I'd need to do some kind of recursion and maybe remove the character so it doesn't affect the next iteration but this clearly isn't working. Any tips would be great.

Comment: What is the function of `*`?

Comment: I would suggest spending a little more time defining how you define your tree before you start writing code to parse it. How do determine that `Captain Morgan` and `Kraken` are siblings and not parent/child?

Comment: It's a delimiter. Anytime that's encountered, the next line would go under the root and the following strings would fall under the previous as children. So in this example, Rum falls under Drinks and Captain Morgan and Kraken fall under Rum. Another * is encountered and so Whiskey falls under Drinks and Laphroaig falls under Whiskey. I'll update question for more clarification

Comment: also you are in C# not json, this is not a list of string `["Drinks", " * ", "Rum", "Captain Morgan", "Kraken", " * ", "Whiskey", "Laphroaig"]` however this might be `var list = new List(){"Drinks", " * ", "Rum", "Captain Morgan", "Kraken", " * ", "Whiskey", "Laphroaig"}`

Comment: Shouldn't there be an asterix before "Drinks" as well, or we know for sure that it is to be the root. One quick way would be just split the list on the "*" and take the first string after it as a child root and add rest of the items in that split list under this child node., assuming that all the levels are shown in the example above.

Comment: It cannot be return as `Drink` class because it only contains 1 record of `drink.name`. Otherwise   you need to return it as `List<Drink>`

Comment: `Rum`,`Captain Morgan`, and `Kraken` are at the same level. How they can be parent child?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thats the problem. Captain Morgan and kraken are supposed to be children.

Comment: I think @peeyushsingh might've given a good hint for a solution

Comment: In that case, you need to think of a new way to represent the tree in the list. The current approach is clearly not the good fit.  Can you explain the use case with some more details? Why you decided to go with this structure to represent the tree? From you retrieve the data? Adding more relevant code with explanation would help..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this code work for you but it is tested as your expected output:

Declaration:

```
 List<Drink> lstdrink = new List<Drink>();

        public List<FinalDrink> lstFinalDrink = new List<FinalDrink>();
```

Class:

```
public class FinalDrink
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
        }
        public class Drink
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int Tag { get; set; }
        }
```

Set Up the Value:

```
 public List<Drink> SetUpTheValue()
        {
            var drinks = new List<string> { "Drinks", " * ", "Rum", "Captain Morgan", "Kraken", " * ", "Whiskey", "Laphroaig" };
            var repl = drinks.Select(s => s.Replace('*', ' ')).ToList();
            string tag = string.Empty;
            Drink drk = new Drink();
            lstdrink = new List<Drink>();
            for (int i = 0; i < repl.Count; i++)
            {


                if (i == 0)
                {
                    drk = new Drink();
                    drk.name = repl[i];
                    drk.Tag = 1;
                    lstdrink.Add(drk);
                    tag = repl[i];
                    continue;
                }

                if (tag.Trim().Length == 0)
                {
                    drk = new Drink();
                    drk.name = repl[i];
                    drk.Tag = 2;
                    lstdrink.Add(drk);
                    tag = repl[i];
                    continue;
                }

                if (repl[i].ToString().Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    drk = new Drink();
                    drk.name = repl[i];
                    drk.Tag = 0;
                    lstdrink.Add(drk);
                    tag = repl[i];
                }

                tag = repl[i];

            }
            return lstdrink;
        }
```

Group Drinks:

```
public List<FinalDrink> GroupDrinks(List<Drink> drinkNames)
        {

            lstFinalDrink = new List<FinalDrink>();
            FinalDrink fDrink = new FinalDrink();
            var GetFirst = drinkNames.Where(x => x.Tag == 1).ToList();
            fDrink.name = GetFirst[0].name.ToString();
            lstFinalDrink.Add(fDrink);
            var Content = drinkNames.Where(x => x.Tag != 1).ToList();
            string itrVal = string.Empty;
            int prev = 0;
            string hcur = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < Content.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (Content[i].Tag == 2)
                {
                    hcur = GetFirst[0].name + " * " + Content[i].name;

                    fDrink = new FinalDrink();
                    itrVal = GetFirst[0].name + " * " + Content[i].name;
                    fDrink.name = itrVal;
                    lstFinalDrink.Add(fDrink);
                    prev = Content[i].Tag;
                    itrVal = string.Empty;

                }

                else
                {
                    fDrink = new FinalDrink();
                    itrVal = hcur + " * " + Content[i].name;
                    fDrink.name = itrVal;
                    lstFinalDrink.Add(fDrink);
                    prev = Content[i].Tag;
                    itrVal = string.Empty;
                }
            }

            return lstFinalDrink;
        }
```

Execution:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (SetUpTheValue().Count() > 0)
            {
                GroupDrinks(lstdrink);
            }
        }
```

The GroupDrinks return `List<FinalDrink>` this is the final result.

It is depend on you to modify the result

This Code will return the expected output as you added from above.